# How can I add float property properly?

Tags: css

On my page http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/pt-build/templatebuild/index.html if you scroll down is a section called pricing. Just below to the right is a div called priceBlock.

I'm currently using this css to float it to the right however somehow the div is being pushed onto the next line.

```
#priceBlock {
width: 206px;
height: 303px;
background: url(../images/pricing-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
float: right;
clear: both;
}
```

The div is within #pricing and there's enough space in the div to fit it in there without it going to another line.

What do I need to change to my css to make it float to the right but be beside the content inside #leftcol within #pricing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your #priceblock rule is clearing the float effectively nullifying the needed effect of the float left of #pricing.  You can fix this behavior by removing the clear both attribute or specifying clear:right:

```
#priceBlock {
    width: 206px;
    height: 303px;
    background: url(../images/pricing-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    float: right;
    clear: right; /*clear: both;*/
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `#priceBlock` remove the property `clear: both;`.